# Service not available: /srv/eng/rdf.search

Tags: geonetwork, search, rdf

After upgrading to GeoNetwork 4.0.1 the rdf.search endpoint is not working. Has it been removed or has something changed?

The documentation, https://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/4.0.x/en/api/rdf-dcat.html, has not changed.

Error message:
Service not available
The service "/catalog/srv/eng/rdf.search" does not exist or you don't have privileges to access it. Return to the search page."

*catalog* is our GeoNetwork instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation page you reference has in text:

> Not yet available in version 4.

Also see:

[Elasticsearch migration / List of missing features](https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/issues/4727)

Comment: D'oh... how could I have missed that. Thank's a lot!